# How to force Facebook JS-SDK to render dynamically added widgets?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The content within the app is being updated using XHR. This involves changing the URL of the comment box:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com?id=[dynamic]" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Upon creating a new Facebook widget placeholder after the page been fully loaded, how do I request Facebook JS SDK to render new elements on the page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call the JavaScript SDK's `FB.XFBML.parse();` function after you dynamically insert the fb-comments div.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/