# FB SDK for when new content loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I've got an interesting problem that took me quite a while to figure out. I have a main website page that has a signup button on it.  When this signup button is clicked, an ajax request is made to load the signup form.  Embedded in the sign up for is this code:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" perms="basic_info" size="medium" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

So I am just trying to load a login button.  Nothing out of the ordinary.

But the login button will only load if I call fb.init AND the code that asynchronously loads the FB SDK within the signup form.  If I try to do these operations when the main page is loaded (and thus before the login button exists), then once the login button markup is loaded, it does not display.  What is the common idiom for resolving this issue?  It is not practical for me to only load the FB SDK from the signup form since it will be used for other things on the main page.  Also, I would prefer to not load the signup form from the start since it is unlikely a user ever clicks the sign up button.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

once you have updated your page

duplicate of
[How to force Facebook JS-SDK to render dynamically added widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454896/how-to-force-facebook-js-sdk-to-render-dynamically-added-widgets)

FB API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/